# jQuery selecting common children in a deep tree

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tree, find, underscore.js

we're looking for a way to select common sibilings in a complex structure... the problem is that the known element is deep within the tree... what we need to find is the common parent dynamically and then select the similar children... without knowing who the common parent is...

eg, we need to find siblings of div.childA

```
table
--tr
----td
------div.childA
--tr
----td
------div.childA
--tr
----td
------div.childA
```

in the above example how would you select all the childA siblings without knowing who the common parent is and the possibility of div.childA existing somewhere else on the page...

the code should also be able to handle other structures such as

```
div
--span
----div
------h1
--------span.childA
div
--span
----div
------h1
--------span.childA
div
--span
----div
------h1
--------span.childA
div
--span
----div
------h1
--------span.childA
```

again need to select all childA, there is also no guarantee that childA has the same class but we can assume that the structure is common for the repeating elements... we just don't know the specific depth.

Comment: I don't think you get what a sibling element is ?

Comment: As a sidenote, something like `$('.childA').closest('table').find('.childA')` would probably solve most of your issues

Comment: if `childA` doesn't have class `childA` how would it be identified per your last comments?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have class of `childA` can easily obtain parent by looping over the collection:

```
$('.childA').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('parentOfChildA')
})
```

Would be `<td>` in first example and `<h1>` in second.